Webスクレイピングでエラーが出て困っています
会社名と会社の住所のリストからスクレイピングで会社のウェブサイトのURLとそのウェブサイトの中の問い合わせフォームのURLを抽出してCSVファイルに書き出すというコードを作りました。
検索にはDuckduckgoを使っています。特にこだわりはないので他の検索でいいものがあれば教えてください。
しかし、会社名を検索してもNoneの値がCSVに入っているだけで
会社のウェブサイトのURLの取得すらできていません。
何か間違っている部分はありますでしょうか。
venvの仮想環境で実行しています。
以下は現在実行しているコードになります。
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
# duckduckgo_searchモジュールをインポートするためには、以下のようにインポート文を追加します
from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
import sys
print(sys.path)
print(sys.executable)
def get_company_url(company_name):
    try:
        with DDGS() as ddgs:
            results = ddgs.text(
                keywords=company_name, 
                region='jp-jp',
                safesearch='moderate',
                time='y',
                max_results=5,
                user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'
            )
        
        for result in results:
            if company_name in result:
                return result
        
        return None
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while searching for {company_name}")
        return None

def get_contact_url(company_url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(company_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        contact_link = soup.find("a", string=["お問い合わせ", "お問い合わせフォーム", "Contact", "contact form"])
        if contact_link:
            contact_url = contact_link.get("href")
            if not contact_url.startswith("http"):
                contact_url = company_url + contact_url
            return contact_url
        else:
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while scraping {company_url}")
        return None

df = pd.read_csv("company_list.csv")

results = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    company_name = row["会社名"]
    company_url = get_company_url(company_name)
    
    print(f"Company URL: {company_url}")
    
    if company_url:
        contact_url = get_contact_url(company_url)
        print(f"Contact URL: {contact_url}")
    else:
        contact_url = None
    
    result = {
        "会社名": company_name,
        "住所": row["住所"],
        "WebサイトURL": company_url,
        "問い合わせフォームURL": contact_url
    }
    results.append(result)
    
    time.sleep(3)  # 各会社の処理の間に3秒の待機時間を設ける

    # 結果をCSVファイルに出力
    df_result = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df_result.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)


マルチポスト⇒ https://qiita.com/ken100/questions/abc018f9bf044352f0f2

スクレイピングは、サイトの管理者に許可を得ているとか、規約に従って専用の API にアクセスしているとかでなければ、迷惑行為になるかもしれないということは認識してますか？クローラーを作って某図書館サイトにアクセスしたら業務妨害とかで逮捕された事例もありますので、甘く見ない方がいいと思います。逮捕までいかなくても、被害が深刻な場合は損害賠償の訴訟を受けるかもしれません。訴訟までいかなくても、アクセス遮断ならWeb サーバーの設定で可能なので、多分に可能性はあると思います。帯域ごと遮断され、あなたのやったことで多数の利用者が巻き添えを喰らうことになるかもしれません。回答するのは迷惑行為の手助けをすることになるかも。

前回の質問は解決したのでしょうか？ そして今回の質問で表示されるエラーメッセージの詳細は何なのでしょうか？ 情報が曖昧な質問が増えたり、問題が変わっていないのに複数の質問をするといったことは解決につながらないと思われます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容をブラッシュアップしてみてください。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, XY問題, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？ あと解決したなら自己回答でもかまいません。自分の質問に回答できますか？

@WebSurfer マルチポスト先の情報を追加するコメントは有意義であることも多いと思いますが、あまりに端的であると、非友好的なものと解釈されるとがあります。
以降は、「マルチポストとは何ですか？」における
「マルチポストを見つけたら」の「良いコメントの例」を参考にし、非友好的と感じられる可能性が無い文面になるようにお願いいたします。

何を「非友好的と感じられる」と言っているのかな？　そこのところをちゃんと書いてくださいな。ここは自分に言わせてもらえればそもそも友好的ではありませんよ。例えば他人の質問を質問者さんの了解なく勝手に書き換えらるところなど

@WebSurfer 非友好的として通報されがちなのは、例えば「マルチポスト⇒ URL」といったような、あまりに端的なコメントなどです。
上に挙げたページや、
「マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント」を参考にして下さい。
なお、このサイトの使い方などに関しては、メタサイトで質問して下さい。
メタサイトに関しては『「メタ」とは？ どのように機能しますか？』をご覧ください。

"例えば「マルチポスト⇒ URL」といったような、あまりに端的なコメント"<= 何を言ってるのかな？　それで十分。端的で十分。本来質問者がやるべきこと。それで、どこにポストしているかが分かる。それ上のことがしたいならあなたがやればいい。モデレータの仕事では？

@WebSurfer 既にご案内の通り、このサイトの運営方針に関しては、メタサイトへ投稿して下さい。
この質問のコメント欄を使っての議論はお止め下さい。
以後、削除などの整理をする可能性が有ります。
（なお、 WebSurfer さんのコメントは全て質問者さんにのみ通知が行われています。
私にも返信したい場合は、先頭で @mjy のようにする必要が有ります
詳しくは「コメントするとどうなりますか？」の箇所をご覧下さい。）

メタサイトとかに行く気は全くないです。"「マルチポスト⇒ URL」といったような、あまりに端的なコメント" も変える気はないです。悪しからず。

マルチポストが何なのかを全人類が知っているわけではないので、ただ「マルチポスト」というワードだけ書かれても「誰宛で」「どんな行動を期待しているのか(=指示がない)」が分からないという点で不親切です。 / "本来質問者がやるべき" というなら、それをそのままコメントで直接伝えれば済む話です。 / モデレーターの仕事(の一つ)は「投稿に無関係なコメントを削除すること」です。

不親切だと思うならあなたが親切になるよう補足すればいい。自分は親切か否かを意識して「マルチポスト⇒ URL」と書いているわけではなくて、マルチポスト先の url を書いておけば、検索などでここを訪れたユーザーが、ここに回答は無くても、url をたどって役に立つ情報を得られるかもという理由だけです。質問者に親切にするためではありません

質問タイトルは「Webスクレイピングでエラーが出て困っています」ですが、本文には「会社名を検索してもNoneの値がCSVに入っているだけで会社のウェブサイトのURLの取得すらできていません。」と書かれておりエラーについては記載がないようです。コードの例外処理を外して問題個所を特定してみてはどうでしょうか？
